# framework not found OpenGLES for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, macos, unity-game-engine, bundle

I have an Xcode Project, it is a Static Library Project. Now I need to make a Unity Plugin for Mac, so I have to convert my static library project to .bundle, I added a new Target in [macOS] -> [Bundle] (my Xcode version is 8.1) I named it as "AoneSDK". The source code from my static library had been compiled it "AoneSDK".

when I build "AoenSDK", the build failed. Error is

> ld:framework not found OpenGLES for architecture x86_64

The "AoneSDK" is a bundle project , so it just supports Mac to build. And I am sure I didn't use OpenGELS.framework at all !!!

Comment: I just want to make a Plugin in Mac, so I have to make my source code into a .bundle .

Comment: may be is not support for simulator try in device

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  yes, it just support Mac , neither  support simulator nor support device. i just want to make a Unity Plugin for Mac , so i have to make a .bundle project.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In short words your static library is not compiled for simulator (x86_64 architecture) try running on a device.

Open a terminal use `lipo -info /path/to/your/library-file` if it doesn't list x86_64 then this library is not compiled for simulatore find a fat library which is compiled for simulator (x86_64 architecture).

Comment: My static library is compiled x86_64 architecture and i can build success,  i just want to make a Unity Plugin for Mac ,so i add a new target which type is a bundle , and i compiled all the source code in my new target ,it occurred the error.  thanks all the same !!!

Comment: I'm facing this issue but I see that is IS compiled for the correct framework. Any idea?
/libpng.a are: armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64